# Trouble removing Stop Words python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to remove stop words from a movie transcript, the stop words and transcript are in separate text files.

```
def stopWords():
    fi = open('stoplist.txt', 'r')
    stopWords = []
    for line in fi:
        line = line.strip()
        stopWords.append(line)
    fi.close
    return None

def readText():
    stopWords()
    fi = open('holy-grail.txt', 'r')
    removeStopWords = ''.join(fi)
    for word in stopWords:
        removeStopWords = removeStopWords.replace(" " + word + " ", " ")
    transcript = []
    for line in fi:
        line = line.strip().lower().split(':')
        transcript.append(line)
    fi.close
    return transcript
```

When I run this code I receive the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    readText()
  File "C:\Users\Adam Sitzmann\Desktop\hw9\hw9.py", line 14, in readText
    for word in stopWords:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: `for word in stopWords:` you're iterating on a function object... and not using the result of your function...

Comment: You need to call `stopwords()`.  Why are you not returning `fi` in `stopwords`? As is, the list gets discarded when the function exits

Answer (score 0):

Here: `for word in stopWords` you try to iterate over a function. You have a naming clash in your code. `stopWords` is both a function and a variable. Name your variable differently.

EDIT:
As you are new to python I'd like to suggest a few improvements:
1. You do not need to write `return None`. Functions without `return` will always give you `None`.
2. Having said that it's worth noticing that you can use `return` to pass the output of `stopWords()` function to process it further.
3. Naming conventions: it's common in python to use `underscored_names` instead of `camelCase`